# C# Linq query to get consecutive data for date range though data is not available in db

Tags: c#, linq

I have a db table with data based on dates

```
Date          sales
09/01/2012    20
09/04/2012    40
```

I need to get data for 20 days as below getting the day it was in that year and also all the missing days as shown.

```
Date         Day      Sales
09/01/2012   Mon      20
09/02/2012   Tue      0
09/03/2012   Wed      0
09/04/2012   Thu      40
09/05/2012   Fri      0.....
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Enumerable.Range` to get a date range and doing a left join should get you going:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2012,09,01);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2012,09,05);

var query = Enumerable.Range(0,(end-start).Days+1)  // range of ints 
        .Select(i => start.AddDays(i))              // range of dates
        .GroupJoin(data,
            d=>d,
            d=>d.Date,
            (d,g)=>new { Date = d, 
                         Day = d.ToString("dddd"), 
                         Sales = g.Any() ? g.Sum(i=>i.Sales) : 0 
                       }
            );
```

Comment: I have a string value in the list the Item icon that i need to show, please help how I can get the icon that is a string (path + icon name from db).    Icon = g.Any() ? g.Select(i => i.ItemIcon).ToString : string.Empty

Comment: I have no idea how that relates to the question or the answer.  Please ask a new question with the details you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Dates` table which has all dates, then you can use that as your source, then left-join against your grouped transaction query. This will be easier to do in SQL than in LINQ, so a stored proc would probably be the way to go instead of doing a LINQ query.

But if you want to do it all in the code, it looks like you already have the grouped data except for the "zero" days, so putting that into the code is easy - define a collection of 20 key-value-pairs (a.k.a. `Dictionary`) representing the 20 dates, then take your data and shove it into that collection.

```
// Very rough - double check the date logic:
var valuesByDate = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
for (DateTime dt = startDate; dt < startDate.AddDays(20); dt = dt.AddDays(1)) {
    valuesByDate[dt] = 0;
}

foreach (var record in recordsFromDb) {
    valuesByDate[record.Date] = record.Sales;
}
```